# Can't get ListView item selected

Tags: android, android-listview, android-event

I am trying to learn how to receive a notification on a click on a radio button in a `ListView` but nothing comes back when I click on a radio button next to a `ListView` item. Below is the code where I set up the listener. I am doing this in an asynchronous task under the `onPostExecute()` method where I populate my `ListView` from the server and my main activity extends `MapActivity`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
    // ... some code
    mapView.postInvalidate();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            viewline);

    ListView restaurant_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    restaurant_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    restaurant_list.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
    restaurant_list.setScrollContainer(true);
    restaurant_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("listargs", (String.valueOf(arg1)) + " " + String.valueOf(arg3));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try onItemClickListener instead.

Comment: At a quick glance, I'm not sure you want to replace the onItemSelectedListener for the ListView by an onItemClickListener for the ListView as the others (so far) suggest. You can also set a Listener for the RadioButton. But of course, this makes quite a difference regarding which area will be touch sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I recommend to you use [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) instead of **OnItemSelectedListener**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View parent,
                           int position, long id) {
      // do your stuff

   }                
});
```

*OnItemClickListener* is usually used when you want to catch click events. *OnItemSelectedListener* is on the other side usually used with Spinner.

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion worked.  I have been following samples from a book and they never mention the OnItemClickListener.  I am trying to make the conversion from C# to Java and it is quite a challenge.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @sajmon_d neither are you. You know there's a 15 minute cooldown.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Cooldown/timeout,etc. The first 15 minutes in which the OP can't accept any answers :-)

Comment: I will accept your answer as working as it does return what I want, which is the index of the clicked listview item.

Comment: Since I am fairly new at this, how do you indicate you have accepted an answer?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK and A--C thanks for cooperation >D i hope that Dave will be back and perform accept.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have focus problem.  Click listener only works if no other view can take focus.

Alter your checkbox xml with the following:

```
focusable="false"
```

Or set it to `false` if you are generating your layouts in code.

Comment: I don't have a checkbox xml as it is part of the ListView parameter using simple_list_item_single_choice as my layout option.

Answer (score 0):

**OnItemSelectedListener** is for trackpad/trackball events

**OnItemClickListener** is for click events

Personaly I **always** implement both for safety.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking that with a ListView, you have to set it to the mode where you can select one ore more items before it issues any _select_ events. But anyway, how do you test that on an AVD? And do you know Android devices which have these input methods?